# POST Method in wp-simple-web-services

Tags: wordpress, web-services

I am using `wp-simple-web-services` plugin for creating API.

Is there any option to get the response from a POST method in the `wp-simple-web-services plugin`.
All the examples are shown with the GET method.

How can I get a POST method in this plugin.?

Comment: Yes, You can. For that you need to customize the plugin.

Comment: What i need to customize for that in plugin

Comment: go to the file named wp-simple-web-services.php you will see this code  // Default webservice
  WPSWS_Webservice_get_posts::get();

Comment: yes.do i need to change that code?

Comment: Yes, put there your logic.

Comment: currently my code is like,// Default webservice
  WPSWS_Webservice_get_posts::get();
  WPSWS_Webservice_login::get(); .Here i want to get login response as POSt.what i need to change here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166391/discussion-between-reshma-and-gufran-hasan).

Comment: @GufranHasan can you help for solving this?

Comment: Please use these two plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/